# Expression Definition in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want to copy data from SharePoint using Synapse's Copy Activity HTTP link service.

I want to put an expression using a function in the formula (1) at the URL of the source data set, but it is not working as expected.

Please let me know how I can fix this.
(1)`https://sharepoint.com/teams/Data/Share/Planning/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Data/Share/Planning/Shared%20Documents/05_master/502_outlet_list/2022/2022_monthly_master/outlet_info_20221101_Outlet List _.xlsx')/$value`

Here is the statement that results in an error
(2)`@concat('https://sharepoint.com/teams/Data/Share/Planning/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Data/Share/Planning/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Data/Share/Planning/Shared%20Documents/05_master/502_outlet_list/',formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(),9),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(),9),'yyyy'),'_monthly_master/outlet_info_',formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(),9),'yyyyMMdd'),'_Outlet List _.xlsx')/$value')`

Comment: The date you are trying to use is `2022-11-01`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. It's right.

Comment: But the `formatDateTime()` used would return the date as `2022-12-07` but not `2022-11-01`

Comment: Oh...I missed it.
However, even if I fix that, I still get an error at the ( ) in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The error is because of the ambiguous usage of single quotes inside `concat` function. Instead, you can use string interpolation `@{...}`.
- You can replace your dynamic content with the below dynamic content which makes use of string interpolation. I have used this in a set variable activity for demonstration.

```
https://sharepoint.com/teams/Data/Share/Planning/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Data/Share/Planning/Shared%20Documents/05_master/502_outlet_list/@{formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(),9),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(),9),'yyyy')}_monthly_master/outlet_info_@{formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(),9),'yyyyMMdd')}_Outlet List _.xlsx')/$value
```

[image]

- This would give the result as shown below:

[image]

- You can modify the `formatDateTime()` function as per your requirement where you can use `2022-11-01` instead of utcNow().